# how to set DateTime.now as current time in Access DataBase - c# windows forms app

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbdataadapter, oledbexception

Im having problems with **An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll ---> data type mismatch in criteria expression** when i try to set the date and time of user's arrival by pressing on button.

How can i set the current date and time of arrival, without getting this error?

**A part of the code**

```
bool clockedIn = false;
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!clockedIn)
        {

            OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("\\CONNECTION PATH");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = myConnection;
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Weekdays (Arrival)" + "values(@Arrival)";


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Arrival", DateTime.now);

            myConnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Arrival added.");
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string query = "insert into table(data) values('"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"')";

OleDbConnection conexao = new OleDbConnection();
conexao.ConnectionString = this.string_conexao;
conexao.Open();

OleDbCommand comando = new OleDbCommand();
comando.CommandText = query;
comando.Connection = conexao;
try
{
comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch
{
}
```